# Connecting Python to an Oracle Database via pyodbc

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to use pyodbc to connect to an oracle database. Below the Python code I have developed:

```
import pyodbc
conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient19Home1};Host=xxxxxx.yyy.com;Port=1521;Service Name=myservicename;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypassword')
```

Unfortunately, the above code does not work as it returns the following error:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\balestram\OneDrive - World Health Organization\Documents\Data Analytics\Python Training> & C:/Users/balestram/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "c:/Users/balestram/OneDrive - World Health Organization/Documents/Data Analytics/Python Training/python"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\OneDrive - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\Documents\Data Analytics\Python Training\python", line 2, in <module>
    conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient19Home1};Host=xxxxxx.yyy.com;Port=1521;Service Name=myservicename;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypassword')
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error\n (12560) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error\n (12560)')
PS C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\OneDrive - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\Documents\Data Analytics\Python Training>
```

I must add that the above connection parameters work well if I connect to the Oracle database with Ms Access and/or Ms Power BI.

Grateful to anyone who could put me on the right track.

Comment: When you connect from MS Access do you use an ODBC DSN? If so, then try `conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=dsn_name;UID=username;PWD=password")` and see if that works.

Comment: If you just want general Python program access to Oracle DB then I'd recommend Oracle's native Python API https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/ instead of pyodbc.  It supports the Python DB API specification and has a lot more features.  And it doesn't need Oracle Client libraries.

Comment: @GordThompson. I have tried the above suggested connection string, but it tells me that the DSN name cannot be found and that no default driver has been specified. Indeed the DSN name exists, and I use it all the time to connect via Access or MS Power BI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below and see if its works.[Taken from the pyodbc documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Oracle-from-RHEL-or-Centos)

```
 pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient19Home1};DBQ=xxxxxx.yyy.com:1521/myservicename;
 UID=myuserid;PWD=mypassword'))"
```

Comment: Interesting. If I use your above code, now I get a different error message, which is:

pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied\n (1017) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied\n (1017)')

However, I am sure 100% that the username and the password are correct as I use them all the time with MS Access, SQL Developer, and MS Power BI.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried again and now it works. I will accept your suggestion as the final solution.